# How to print out numbers and theirs squares in a range?

Tags: python, loops, printing

So if I have:

```
lower = int(input("Enter the lower limit: "))
upper = int(input("Enter the upper limit: "))
```

How do I print each number in between the lower limit (inclusive) and the upper limit (inclusive) along with each of their squares?

For example:

User Input:

```
Enter the lower limit: 1
Enter the upper limit: 5
```

Expected Output

```
Numbers: 1,2,3,4,5
Squares: 1,4,9,16,25
```

Comment: Can you show your code please? What parts of it are giving you difficulty?

Comment: @idjaw I am new to Python and all I know so far is how to do simple things like adding numbers and starting single for loops, but I want to do more and I'm not sure how to start the code after the inputs from the user

Comment: Take it a step at a time. You have your inputs. Your first task is to output them from lower limit to upper limit. You said you know how to use your loop. That is your first. Now, someone might just give you the answer here. But, I don't mind helping you figure it out on your own. Look up "range" in python and try to get the first part. Come back and post your code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
lower = int(input("Enter the lower limit: "))
upper = int(input("Enter the upper limit: "))
List = (range(lower, upper + 1))
squared = [x ** 2 for x in List]
print "Numbers: " + ",".join(str(x) for x in List)
print "Squares: " + ",".join(str(x)for x in squared)
```

Comment: @idjaw sorry for not letting him figure it out first. Didn't read your post until afterword.

Comment: So I got the code above but I'm not sure how to print it out excluding the brackets

Comment: I edited it to remove the brackets and don't forget to mark the best answer :)